# Calling a regular expression in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, expression

I've spent many hours trying to work this out. I know it's something easy but it just will not work for me!

I would like to validate for a password using this expression `^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` with javascript.

I'm not sure how to structure the function and how to call it in the code. I've got something working for validating the email but I can't make the password expression work.

```
function validateEmail()
{     
   var emailID = document.myForm.email.value;
   atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
   dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
   if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
   {
       alert("Please enter correct email address")
       document.myForm.email.focus() ;
       return false;
   }
   return( true );
}

function validate()
{
    if( document.myForm.email.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
         document.myForm.email.focus() ;
         return false;
       }
    else
       {
         // Put extra check for data format
         var ret = validateEmail();
         if( ret == false )
         {
            return false;
       }
}
```

I would like to call the passwordChecker from the validate function.

Comment: why cant you just call passwordChecker(); like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
function validateEmail()
{     
   var emailID = document.myForm.email.value;
   atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
   dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
   if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) 
   {
       alert("Please enter correct email address")
       document.myForm.email.focus() ;
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function validatePassword()
{     
   var reg = /^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
   return reg.test(document.myForm.password.value);       
}

function validate()
{
    if(document.myForm.email.value == "" || !validateEmail())
    {
         alert( "Please provide a valid Email!" );
         document.myForm.email.focus() ;
         return false;
    }
    else if(!validatePassword())
    {
         alert("Please provide a valid password!");
         document.myForm.password.focus() ;
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much billy! It makes so much more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

```
function isEmail(email) {     
   var re = /^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; 
   return re.test(email); 
}

function validate() {
    var email = document.myForm.email;
    if (email.value.trim() =="") { // may need IE support
      alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
      email.focus() ;
      return false;
    }
    if (!isEmail(email.value)) {
      alert( "Please provide a valid Email!" );
      email.focus() ;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```